# Installing Windows Vista SP1 causes Startup Repair to launch on reboot (SP1 installation fails)

Tags: windows-vista, service-pack

I am trying to install Windows Vista Service Pack 1, but whenever the computer reboots it runs Startup Repair, before claiming that it can't fix the problem its found. It's then possible to boot into Windows Vista, but the service pack hasn't installed.

Any idea how to go about fixing this so I can get SP1 installed?

Comment: Upgrade to the more stable Windows 7?

Comment: Ha! Not an option I'm afraid, it's a client's machine; the client has a disability so is living on benefits/social security

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got SP1 to install via Windows Update (I'd previously been using the standalone installer). SP2 then installed fine, using the standalone installer. No idea what caused this.

Comment: The stand alone installer likely was trying to install something that was incompatible with the system the windows update streamed only what the system needed